# PHP integration with Clicatell SMTP API

Tags: php, email, smtp, clickatell

I am trying to sent up a php that will sent email to Clicatell SMTP api. The idea is simple - making calls using PHP SOAP client to SQL server, getting the reply and the inserting this reply into email body sent to Clicatell server.

```
<?php

$to = 'sms@messaging.clickatell.com';

$today = strtoupper(date('dMy')); 
$subject = 'Test sms sent on ' . $today;

// API request and response goes here 
//this is how the response from the api looks like

$response ='To:4412345677693\r\nTo:4412345665693\r\nTo:4412375677693\r\nTo:4463879456776\r\n';  

$message = 'api_id: 12345678\r\nuser:user1234\r\npassword:PxAxSxSxWxOxRxD\r\n' . $response . 'Reply: youremail@yourdomain.com\r\ntext:Test Message Using Clickatell api\r\n'; 

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8' . '\r\n';
$headers = 'From: no-reply@example.com' . '\r\n' .

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

This should hopefully produce email in plain text looking like:

```
To: sms@messaging.clickatell.com

api_id: 12345678
User: user1234
Password: PxAxSxSxWxOxRxD
To:4412345677693
To:4412345665693
To:4412375677693
To:4463879456776
Reply: youremail@yourdomain.com
text: Test Message Using Clickatell api
```

However I am getting everything on just one line. And help would be appreciated.

Comment: `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** understand/honor escape sequences. So the `\r\n` you have in there are literal backslashes and literal r/n characters. The only acceptable escape in `'`-quoted strings is a `\\` itself. Use `"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the quotes to double quotes to handle control characters properly:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: no-reply@example.com\r\n";
```

The same should be applied to $response and $message.
Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because you are setting `Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8` in the headers, so you would have to use `<br>` to get a newline.

Since you want plain text instead of HTML, you need to use a more appropriate content-type.  Try using `Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1` for example.

---

Another thing to consider is (as per php manual) some relays will "incorrectly" convert `"\n"` in the text to `"\r\n"` on UNIX systems.  Recommendation is to use PHP EOF constant instead of `"\r\n"`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

---

Also using single-quoted strings, you will find the the `'\r\n'` does not treat the `\` as an escape character.  You may need to use double-quoted strings such as `"\r\n"` to get the desired behavior.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: This was my idea as well, however did not helped at all. Still going trough as email on one line

Comment: Have you checked into using `"\n"` vs. `"\r\n"` vs. `'\r\n'` vs. using PHP EOF constant?  Answer is updated with some additional notes about this, also see the PHP manual page referenced in the updated answer.

Comment: Hi, I have changed ' to " and it works! Thanks a lot. I will keep using always "  instead of '